# Making a function to abstract a web2py DB call

Tags: web2py

I'm using web2py with its DAL. I want to do a function (for several reasons as code readability, abstracting from web2py…) that will perform a select on the DB. For instance:

```
def get_element_from_id(id, *options):
  return db(db.element.id == id).select(options)
```

The function is quite basic but it doesn't work. If I provide no option (just calling `get_element_from_id(1)`), I have a wonderful:

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'type'

If I provide an option (for instance `get_element_from_id(1, db.element.id)`), I get a:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function, `options` will be a list, but `.select()` does not take a list, so you must use the `*` notation to expand the list into a set of arguments:

```
.select(*options)
```

Also, to make the function more general, you might also want to allow the keyword arguments of the `.select()` method -- so:

```
def get_element_from_id(id, *args, **kwargs):
    return db(db.element.id == id).select(*args, **kwargs)
```

Also, note that if you just want to retrieve the whole record based on the ID, the DAL already allows you to do this:

```
db.element(id)
```

Comment: Perfect thanks :)
For the `db.element(id)`, actually I don't select on the ID, it was just a (poorly chosen) example.

Comment: If you just need a single record, you can use the above syntax with any combination of fields -- for example, `db.element(field1='a', field2='b')`. That method will return the first matching record (or `None` if no records match). It even takes `_orderby` and `_for_update` arguments. This is documented [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Fetching-a-Row).